# Not all messages sent via Producer.Produce() make it to Kafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka

When I use below code to produce about 4M messages (read in from a 2.5GB file), a fair share of messages (between 640k and 730k, fluctuating from invocation to invocation) doesn't make it into the Kafka topic - I'm using a standalone broker on localhost. The output is something like this:

```
Still flushing... (8711 unflushed events)
Sent 3651628/4384003 records to kafka
```

The (fluctuating) number of messages that actually make it into Kafka exactly equals `eventCount`, and there are no errors. What could be the cause for this?

```golang
func write(broker string, records chan *read.KVRecord) {
    p, err := kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error creating producer: %s\n", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.Close()

    var eventCount int64
    go func() {
        for e := range p.Events() {
            switch ev := e.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:
                eventCount++
                if ev.TopicPartition.Error != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Delivery failed: %v\n", ev.TopicPartition)
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    var sendCount int64
    for r := range records {
        p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &r.Topic Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
            Key:            r.Key,
            Value:          r.Value,
        }, nil)
        sendCount++
    }
    unflushed := p.Flush(0)
    for unflushed > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Still flushing... (%d unflushed messages)\n", unflushed)
        unflushed = p.Flush(1000)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Sent %d/%d records to kafka\n", eventCount, sendCount)
}
```

Comment: Your program is racy. Protect access to `eventCount` with a mutex, or use sync/atomic to increment it. There is no guarantee that the main goroutine sees the final value of `eventCount`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar eventCount is not supposed to be part of the program, I just added it when the Kafka topic had less messages than sendCount, so I'm not worried about eventCount. eventCount as `fmt.Printf()`ed is however exactly equal to the number of messages in the kafka topic (that I always empty before running this test). Also, I'm getting the eventCount value only after all messages have been flushed, and I bet kafka is synchronizing under the hood, which is why this works in practice. In any event, eventCount will go away as soon as I found the problem.

Comment: Use Kafka stats to know how much messages did you write to the topic. Maybe you have read problem. I used https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

Comment: @ZAky What do you mean by "read problem"? I'm only writing (producing) in this case. I will take a look at kafka-go - interesting, because it seems to be easily cross-compilable (in contrast to confluent-kafka-go)

Comment: How do you know that not all messages are written to the topic? You read the topic and get less messages, I guess. We need to be sure that the reader is not the problem.

Comment: @ZAky I'm reading using a standard tool (kafkacat). Also, that read number matches exactly the first number in the `Sent ... to kafka` log in my question. So it's clear it's happening inside my go writer process.

Comment: If you just use the producer sample code from https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go as as, you still have this problem?